# How to pass string to an array of PAnsiChar?

Tags: string, delphi, unicode, casting, delphi-xe2

Something strange happens when I try to pass strings from the `Lines` of a `TMemo` control to an array of `PChar`. At the end of the routine, the last string in the array is duplicated. I was able to replicate this in this simple code:

```
procedure Test;
var
  i: smallint;
  arr: array of PAnsiChar;
  strarr: array[0..1] of string;
begin
  SetLength(arr, 2);
  strarr[0] := 'abbb';
  strarr[1] := 'baaa';

  for i := 0 to Length(strarr) do
    arr[i] := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(strarr[i]));
end;
```

If I run this procedure step by step, I can see `arr[0] = 'abbb'` however, at the end of the rutine, both values, `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` equal to `baaa`. I guess it has something to do with the typecast.

Can anyone see what is wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. Your loop is exceeding the upper bound of the array.  It needs to use `for i := 0 to Length(strarr)-1 do` or `for i := 0 to High(strarr) do` instead.
2. More importantly, when you type-cast an `AnsiString` to a `PAnsiChar`, it returns a pointer to the `AnsiString`'s internal data if the `AnsiString` is not empty.  You are type-casting a `UnicodeString` to an `AnsiString` and grabbing a pointer into it, so the compiler has to use a compiler-generated local variable for the `AnsiString` data.  In other words, your code is effectively doing the same thing as the following:

   ```
   procedure Test;
   var
     i: smallint;
     arr: array of PAnsiChar;
     strarr: array[0..1] of string;
     compiler_temp: AnsiString;
   begin
     SetLength(arr, 2);
     strarr[0] := 'abbb';
     strarr[1] := 'baaa';
     for i := 0 to Length(strarr) do
     begin
       compiler_temp := AnsiString(strarr[i]);
       arr[i] := PAnsiChar(compiler_temp);
     end;
   end;
   ```

Depending on how the memory for `compiler_temp` gets managed by the RTL memory manager at run-time, it is certainly possible for `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` to end up pointing at the same physical memory block in this situation.

If you want an array of `PAnsiChar` values then you need to start with an array of `Ansi` data for them to point at:

```
procedure Test;
var
  i: Integer;
  arr: array of PAnsiChar;
  strarr: array[0..1] of AnsiString;
begin
  SetLength(arr, 2);
  strarr[0] := 'abbb';
  strarr[1] := 'baaa';
  for i := 0 to Length(strarr)-1 do
    arr[i] := PAnsiChar(strarr[i]);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy. I had a quick look at the Delphi and Unicode white paper and they suggest using RawByteString types when passing strings to functions so I typecasted the strings to RawByteStrings before adding them to the array and it works fine, although I don't know why.

Comment: `RawByteString` is primarily meant to be used only in parameters for functions that are codepage-agnostic and accept any `AnsiString(N)` type as input. `RawByteString` inherits the codepage of whatever source string is assigned to it. Type-casting a `UnicodeString` to a `RawByteString` is exactly the same thing as type-casting a `UnicodeString` to an `AnsiString`, since both involve the `System.DefaultSystemCodePage` global variable as the codepage for the Unicode->Ansi conversion.

Comment: `RawByteString` is generally not meant to be used outside of that context, but people tend to do so anyway. Don't rely on the behavior you see, since it is outside the scope of its purpose. Make your code do the "right thing" instead.

Comment: Have been looking for about a 8h for this solution. It really works.